# A body kept inside a perfectly black body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, thermal-radiation

A spherical body of area A and emissivity e=0.6 is kept inside a perfectly black body. Total heat radiated by the body per second at temperature T is?

The options are

a.) 0.4 sigma AT^4

b.) 0.6 sigma AT^4

c.) 0.8 sigma AT^4

d.) 1 sigma AT^4

I  know that according to the Stefan-Boltzmann law that the heat radiated by any body is e*sigma*AtT^4 but I don't know what difference will it make if we place this body inside a perfectly black body.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a black body cavity with a temperature $T$, and you place a second body inside the cavity, then at equilibrium the second body will have the same temperature $T$. This has to be the case because if the second body equilibrated to a different temperature we could connect a heat engine between the two bodies and extract an infinite amount of work.

This is an important principle that you will encounter in many different situations. And now you know the temperature of the second body is also $T$ it is easy to calculate the power emitted using the Stefan-Boltzmann equation.

Note that the emissivity and transmissivity are the same, so at equilibrium the power radiated is the same as the power absorbed, which of course it needs to be for the system to be at equilibrium.

Comment: Hi John,so the answer you suggest is option d,right?